# Witch storing wizard spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch

Can a witch study a wizard/sorcerer or cleric spell from a scroll and store it in their familiar if it's not on their witch spell list?

Comment: [*Maybe* a dupe?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57008/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan: The way I'm reading things, this question is asking about storing the witch's learned spells in the familiar, like a spellbook, while the other question is about teaching the familiar to cast a spell itself. But looking through the linked documentation on both questions, it looks like familiars can't actually cast the spells themselves, so what I thought the other question is asking isn't even possible. In which case it looks like a dupe to me. My specific concern is the verbiage "teach" rather than "store", but it's under a heading that says "add spells to a witch's familiar".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[No.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/witch-s-familiar)

> A witch’s familiar only stores witch spells.